# Issue with dateByAddingTimeInterval

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Hi I'm trying to add days to current date using dateByAddingTimeInterval. It doesn't show any error but the app crashes when I submit the form:

```
 var newDate = NSDate()
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy"
        var interval: Double!

        if self.unit == "D" {
            var aTime = Double(loadTime.toInt()!) * 24 * 60 * 60
            var interval = NSTimeInterval(aTime)
        } else if self.unit == "H" {
            var aTime = Double(loadTime.toInt()!) * 60 * 60
            var interval = NSTimeInterval(aTime)
        }

        var EndDate = newDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)
        var EndDateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(EndDate)
        product["loadEndDate"] = EndDateStr
```

The Debug navigator shows error with this line:
            var EndDate = newDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)

Can somebody please tell where I'm doing wrong? I went through many online helps but didn't find anything that could help in my case.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

```
let today = NSDate()
let tommorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: today, options: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

each `var` keyword creates a new variable, you are creating new interval variables in the if - else expression with the scope between the braces. The first interval variable, which is later used is nil

Improved syntax

```
    var newDate = NSDate()
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy"
    let interval: NSTimeInterval // let and not optional

    if self.unit == "D" {
        interval = NSTimeInterval(loadTime.toInt()! * 24 * 60 * 60)
    } else if self.unit == "H" {
        interval = NSTimeInterval(loadTime.toInt()! * 60 * 60)
    }

    var endDate = newDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)
    var endDateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(endDate)
    product["loadEndDate"] = endDateStr
```

Comment: Thanks, and really sorry for those silly mistakes that I overlooked in hurry. I am confused with your solution: You've defined: let interval: NSTimeInterval. However, you've again assigned a new value to it inside the 'if' statement. And what should be the initial value of 'interval' since it's being defined in global scope.

Comment: a `let` statement is allowed, if the variable is guaranteed to be initialized always once (in one of the if - else branches). Then the variable can be declared as non-optional which makes the code more type-safe

Answer (score 0):

This one worked:

```
 var newDate = NSDate()
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy"
    var interval: Double! = 0.0

    if self.unit == "D" {
        var aTime = Double(loadTime.toInt()!) * 24 * 60 * 60
        interval = NSTimeInterval(aTime)
    } else if self.unit == "H" {
        var aTime = Double(loadTime.toInt()!) * 60 * 60
        interval = NSTimeInterval(aTime)
    }

    var EndDate = newDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval)
    var EndDateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(EndDate)
    product["loadEndDate"] = EndDateStr
```

All I did is I removed the 'var' from 'var interval' from inside the if loop (this is ridiculously stupid :P) and gave an initial value to the interval variable. But I think it was the 'var' that was messing up.

Thanks again,

Comment: Every developer who uses 86.400 seconds to represent a day deserves the headache it will cause one day.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thank you for your comment, can you please elaborate what you're saying? Not sure, why seconds would cause issue since it's the most minute unit to deal with date and time?

Comment: Ever heard of daylight saving time?